# Ajax display results without page refresh

Tags: ajax

I have the below form that I am trying to get to when the submit button is clicked to have the results shown on the page in the div with id "storelisting" without the page refreshing.

The issue is when I click the submit button it still just reloads the page? also it does not even show any results in the storelisting id dive when the page is refreshed?

```
<form id="mullerlocator" method="POST">
            <label>Plz: </label>
        <input type="text" name="postcode" maxlength="6" style="display:inline!important; width:100px!important"/> <label>Radius: </label>
        <select name="radius""><option value='5'>5 km</option><option value='10'>10 km</option><option value='15'>15 km</option><option value='20'>20 km</option></select><br />
        <input type="submit" name="locationsearch" id="mullersubmit" value="Search" style="display:inline!important" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <div id="storelisting"></div>
         <script>
                  $( "#mullersubmit" ).submit(function( event ) 
                  {
                        $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "http://www.kissnypro.de/test2/test.php",
                              data: $( "#mullerlocator" ).serialize(),
                              success: function(data){
                                  //print here 
                                  $("#storelisting").html(data);
                              },
                              dataType: 'html' // for json response or 'html' for html response
                             });
                  }
            </script>
```

And this is my test.php code

```
if(isset($_POST['locationsearch']))
{
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $distance = $_POST['radius'];
     echo "Suche mit $distance km von $postcode<br />
      <table class='table table-responsive'>
                 <thead><th>address</th><th>Distance</th></thead>";

                        $mullerconn = mysqli_connect('localhost', '....', '....') or die('db connect error: ' . mysqli_error());
                        mysqli_select_db($mullerconn, '....') or die('could not select database');

                        $sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM german_zipcodes WHERE zipcode = $postcode";
                        $result = mysqli_query($mullerconn, $sqlstring);

                        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                        $lng = $row["longitude"] / 180 * M_PI;
                        $lat = $row["latitude"] / 180 * M_PI;
                        mysqli_free_result($result);

                        //lets see if any store matches the exact zipcode entered
                        $exactlocationsql = mysqli_query($mullerconn, "SELECT * FROM muller_locations WHERE zip_code ='$postcode'");
                        $numexactrows = mysqli_num_rows($exactlocationsql);
                        $exactrow = mysqli_fetch_array($exactlocationsql);
                        extract($exactrow);

                        $str = "<tr><td>$street_address $city $zip_code</td><td> 0 km</td></tr>";

                        $sqlstring2 = "SELECT DISTINCT german_zipcodes.zipcode,(6367.41*SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.latitude))*cos(".$lat.")*(sin(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.longitude))*sin(".$lng.")+cos(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.longitude))*cos(".$lng."))-sin(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.latitude))* sin(".$lat.")))) AS Distance FROM german_zipcodes AS german_zipcodes WHERE (6367.41*SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.latitude))*cos(".$lat.")*(sin(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.longitude))*sin(".$lng.")+cos(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.longitude))*cos(".$lng."))-sin(RADIANS(german_zipcodes.latitude))*sin(".$lat."))) <= '".$distance."') ORDER BY Distance desc LIMIT 5";

                        $result = mysqli_query($mullerconn, $sqlstring2) or die('query failed: ' . mysqli_error());

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            $thezipcodeis = $row['zipcode'];
                            $thedistance = round($row['Distance']);

                            //lets look for muller stores in this location 
                            $mullersql = mysqli_query($mullerconn, "SELECT * from muller_locations WHERE zip_code ='$thezipcodeis' order by city desc");
                            $numlocations = mysqli_num_rows($mullersql);
                            while($locationrows = mysqli_fetch_array($mullersql))
                            {
                                extract($locationrows);
                                $str .= "<tr><td>$street_address $city $zip_code</td><td> $thedistance km</td></tr>";
                            }     



                        }

                        if($numexactrows == 0 && $numlocations == 0)
                        {
                            echo "Keine Muller-Standorte haben übereinstimmende Suchkriterien gefunden";
                        }   
                         else
                        {
                            echo "$str";
                        }
    echo "</table>";
    }
    mysqli_close($mullerconn);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a form submit will cause the page to refresh and post back to your server for further execution. Since you are making use of JavaScript to send the form contents back to the server for processing, add the following line in your JavaScript function:

```
$( "#mullersubmit" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); // <---- Add this line

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.kissnypro.de/test2/test.php",
        data: $( "#mullerlocator" ).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            // print here 
            $("#storelisting").html(data);
        },
        dataType: 'html' // for json response or 'html' for html response
    });
});
```

Preventing the `default` form event will stop the page from reloading on form submission.

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent the actual submit

```
$(function() {
    $('form#mullerlocator').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post('test.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            $("#storelisting").html(data);
        }).error(function() {
            // This is executed when the call to test.php failed.
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```